# How to insert data into druid via tranquility

Tags: druid

By following tutorial at http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-loading-streaming-data.html , I was able to insert data into druid via Kafka console

### Kafka console

The spec file looks as following

**examples/indexing/wikipedia.spec**

```
[
  {
    "dataSchema" : {
      "dataSource" : "wikipedia",
      "parser" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "parseSpec" : {
          "format" : "json",
          "timestampSpec" : {
            "column" : "timestamp",
            "format" : "auto"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec" : {
            "dimensions": ["page","language","user","unpatrolled","newPage","robot","anonymous","namespace","continent","country","region","city"],
            "dimensionExclusions" : [],
            "spatialDimensions" : []
          }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec" : [{
        "type" : "count",
        "name" : "count"
      }, {
        "type" : "doubleSum",
        "name" : "added",
        "fieldName" : "added"
      }, {
        "type" : "doubleSum",
        "name" : "deleted",
        "fieldName" : "deleted"
      }, {
        "type" : "doubleSum",
        "name" : "delta",
        "fieldName" : "delta"
      }],
      "granularitySpec" : {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "DAY",
        "queryGranularity" : "NONE"
      }
    },
    "ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "realtime",
      "firehose": {
        "type": "kafka-0.8",
        "consumerProps": {
          "zookeeper.connect": "localhost:2181",
          "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" : "15000",
          "zookeeper.session.timeout.ms" : "15000",
          "zookeeper.sync.time.ms" : "5000",
          "group.id": "druid-example",
          "fetch.message.max.bytes" : "1048586",
          "auto.offset.reset": "largest",
          "auto.commit.enable": "false"
        },
        "feed": "wikipedia"
      },
      "plumber": {
        "type": "realtime"
      }
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type" : "realtime",
      "maxRowsInMemory": 500000,
      "intermediatePersistPeriod": "PT10m",
      "windowPeriod": "PT10m",
      "basePersistDirectory": "\/tmp\/realtime\/basePersist",
      "rejectionPolicy": {
        "type": "messageTime"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I start **realtime** via

```
java -Xmx512m -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Ddruid.realtime.specFile=examples/indexing/wikipedia.spec -classpath config/_common:config/realtime:lib/* io.druid.cli.Main server realtime
```

In Kafka console, I paste and enter the following

```
{"timestamp": "2013-08-10T01:02:33Z", "page": "Good Bye", "language" : "en", "user" : "catty", "unpatrolled" : "true", "newPage" : "true", "robot": "false", "anonymous": "false", "namespace":"article", "continent":"North America", "country":"United States", "region":"Bay Area", "city":"San Francisco", "added": 57, "deleted": 200, "delta": -143}
```

Then I tend to perform query by creating `select.json` and run `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8084/druid/v2/?pretty' -H 'content-type: application/json'  -d @select.json`

**select.json**

```
 {
   "queryType": "select",
   "dataSource": "wikipedia",
   "dimensions":[],
   "metrics":[],
   "granularity": "all",
   "intervals": [
     "2000-01-01/2020-01-02"
   ],

   "filter" : {"type":"and",
        "fields" : [
                { "type": "selector", "dimension": "user", "value": "catty" }
        ]
   },

   "pagingSpec":{"pagingIdentifiers": {}, "threshold":500}
 }
```

I was able to get the following result.

```
[ {
  "timestamp" : "2013-08-10T01:02:33.000Z",
  "result" : {
    "pagingIdentifiers" : {
      "wikipedia_2013-08-10T00:00:00.000Z_2013-08-11T00:00:00.000Z_2013-08-10T00:00:00.000Z" : 0
    },
    "events" : [ {
      "segmentId" : "wikipedia_2013-08-10T00:00:00.000Z_2013-08-11T00:00:00.000Z_2013-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
      "offset" : 0,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2013-08-10T01:02:33.000Z",
        "continent" : "North America",
        "robot" : "false",
        "country" : "United States",
        "city" : "San Francisco",
        "newPage" : "true",
        "unpatrolled" : "true",
        "namespace" : "article",
        "anonymous" : "false",
        "language" : "en",
        "page" : "Good Bye",
        "region" : "Bay Area",
        "user" : "catty",
        "deleted" : 200.0,
        "added" : 57.0,
        "count" : 1,
        "delta" : -143.0
      }
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

It seem that I had setup Druid correctly.

Now, I would like to insert data via HTTP endpoint. According to [How realtime data input to Druid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630369/how-realtime-data-input-to-druid), it seems like recommended way is to use `tranquility`

### tranquility

I have indexing service started via

```
java -Xmx2g -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath config/_common:config/overlord:lib/*: io.druid.cli.Main server overlord
```

**conf/server.json** looks like

```
{
   "dataSources" : [
      {
         "spec" : {
            "dataSchema" : {
                "dataSource" : "wikipedia",
                "parser" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "parseSpec" : {
                      "format" : "json",
                      "timestampSpec" : {
                        "column" : "timestamp",
                        "format" : "auto"
                      },
                      "dimensionsSpec" : {
                        "dimensions": ["page","language","user","unpatrolled","newPage","robot","anonymous","namespace","continent","country","region","city"],
                        "dimensionExclusions" : [],
                        "spatialDimensions" : []
                      }
                    }
                },
                "metricsSpec" : [{
                    "type" : "count",
                    "name" : "count"
                }, {
                    "type" : "doubleSum",
                    "name" : "added",
                    "fieldName" : "added"
                }, {
                    "type" : "doubleSum",
                    "name" : "deleted",
                    "fieldName" : "deleted"
                }, {
                    "type" : "doubleSum",
                    "name" : "delta",
                    "fieldName" : "delta"
                }],
                "granularitySpec" : {
                    "type" : "uniform",
                    "segmentGranularity" : "DAY",
                    "queryGranularity" : "NONE"
                }
            },
            "tuningConfig" : {
               "windowPeriod" : "PT10M",
               "type" : "realtime",
               "intermediatePersistPeriod" : "PT10M",
               "maxRowsInMemory" : "100000"
            }
         },
         "properties" : {
            "task.partitions" : "1",
            "task.replicants" : "1"
         }
      }
   ],
   "properties" : {
      "zookeeper.connect" : "localhost",
      "http.port" : "8200",
      "http.threads" : "8"
   }
}
```

Then, I start the server using

```
bin/tranquility server -configFile conf/server.json
```

I perform post to http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8200/v1/post/wikipedia, with `content-type` equals `application/json`

```
{"timestamp": "2013-08-10T01:02:33Z", "page": "Selamat Pagi", "language" : "en", "user" : "catty", "unpatrolled" : "true", "newPage" : "true", "robot": "false", "anonymous": "false", "namespace":"article", "continent":"North America", "country":"United States", "region":"Bay Area", "city":"San Francisco", "added": 57, "deleted": 200, "delta": -143}
```

I get the the following respond

```
{"result":{"received":1,"sent":0}}
```

***It seems that tranquility has received our data, but failed to send it to druid!***

I try to run `curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8084/druid/v2/?pretty' -H 'content-type: application/json'  -d @select.json`, but doesn't get the output I inserted via tranquility.

Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It dropped messages because of timestamp in your docs were outside your windowPeriod. i.e your timestamp should be within 10M from server time.

Comment: Thanks. I don't realize druid + tranquility setup can't accept old data, as my previous testing with druid + kafka console, it can accept old data. Is it because tranquility talks to druid's indexing node, and kafka console talks to druid's realtime node?

Comment: It depends on what type rejectionPolicy you are using. You used messageTime rejection policy while ingesting through realtime node whereas in tranquility it was set to default which is serverTime. For more information you can read about rejectionPolicy and windowPeriod.

Comment: @avr does Tranquility support `rejectionPolicy=messageTime` ? I wanna use it for indexing hourly batches that we are indexing by hadoop indexing tasks just to avoid depending on S3. Btw do you know whether `druid.coordinator.merge.on` will work on segments indexed by Tranquility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ***extremely difficult*** to setup druid to work properly with real-time data insertion.

The best bet I found is, use https://github.com/implydata . Imply is a set of wrappers around druid, to make it easy to use.

However, the real-time insertion in imply is not perfect either. I had experiment `OutOfMemoryException`, after inserting 30 millions items via real-time. This will caused data loss on previous inserted 30 millions rows.

The detailed regarding data loss can be found here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/imply-user-group/95xpYojxiOg

An issue ticket has been filed : https://github.com/implydata/distribution/issues/8

Comment: Hi Cheok! I was wondering if you can help me out with this problem I have in Druid when submitting a query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546593/how-to-perform-a-select-in-the-results-returned-from-a-group-by-druid/38574257#38574257

Comment: Cheok, do you have any link on how to setup implydata, do you need to purchase something from imply?

Answer (score 3):

This generally happens when the data you send is out of the window period. If you are inserting data manually, give the exact current timestamp (UTC) in milliseconds. Else it can be easily done if you are using any script to generate data. Make sure it is UTC current time.

Answer (score 0):

Druid streaming windowPeriod is very short (10 minutes). Outside this period, your event will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As you got {"result":{"received":1,"sent":0}}, your worker threads are working fine. Tranquility decides what data is sent to the druid based on the timestamp associated with the data.

This period is decided by the "windowPeriod" configuration. So if your type is realtime ("type":"realtime") and window period is PT10M ("windowPeriod" : "PT10M"), tranquility will send any data between t-10, t+10 and not send anything outside this period.

I disagree with the insertion efficiency problems, we have been sending 3million rows every 15 minutes since June 2016 and has been running beautifully. Of course, we have a stronger infrastructure deemed for the scale.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for not inserting, is out memory on the coordinador/overloard  are running