# Feed druid with data from graylog2 server

Tags: graylog2, druid

Dears

I need to get data from graylog2 server into druid (e.g. CPU, memory, disk utilisation of several machines).

I've searched for plugins at the graylog marketplace and tranquility documentation, and I did not found any solution to retrieve data from graylog2.

I believe the solution is to use the REST API from graylog2, but how can this be "automated" from the druid/[tranquility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980372/how-to-insert-data-into-druid-via-tranquility) side?

Answer (score 0):

Looked quickly into the Graylog2, i couldn't find any doc or like about the REST API that you have mention, neither a documented way about how to extract data in general from Graylog2. But if you can come up with something that can read from Graylog2 and dump to kafka you can point the druid cluster to that kafka topics and ingest the data.